# room migration: Test instrumentation process crashed

Tags: android, android-room

**Problem Background** : Crash while testing room migrations -

*Test instrumentation process crashed. Check MigrationTest#migrationFrom5To6_containsCorrectData.txt for details.*

Sample Taken from [MigrationTest.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceMigrationsSample/app/src/androidTestRoom2/java/com/example/android/persistence/migrations/MigrationTest.java)

**Trials** - Haven't had any luck but here is is what I tried so far.

- When debugging the test execution process goes forever.
- If I just try to put couple print statement in `migrationFrom5To6_containsCorrectData` nothing gets printed. So my blind guess is something is wrong in the setup process which is `getMigratedRoomDatabase`.

**TextFile Details**

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

**RoomVersion**: 1.1.1-rc1

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) public class MigrationTest {

    @Rule public MigrationTestHelper testHelper =
        new MigrationTestHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
            SampleDb.class.getCanonicalName(), new FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory());

    private static final String TEST_DB_NAME = "test-db";

    private static final User FIRST_USER = createDummyUser(true);
    private static final User SECOND_USER = createDummyUser(false);

    @Test public void migrationFrom5To6_containsCorrectData() throws Exception {
        //Create the database in version 4
        SupportSQLiteDatabase db = testHelper.createDatabase(TEST_DB_NAME, 5);
        // Insert some data
        insertUser(FIRST_USER, db);
        insertUser(SECOND_USER, db);
        //Prepare for the next version
        db.close();

        // Re-open the database with version 6 and provide MIGRATION_4_6
        // and MIGRATION_5_6 as the migration process.
        testHelper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB_NAME, 6, true, MIGRATION_2_6, MIGRATION_4_6,
            MIGRATION_5_6);

        // MigrationTestHelper automatically verifies the schema
        //changes, but not the data validity
        // Validate that the data was migrated properly.
        UserDao dbUser = getMigratedRoomDatabase().userDao();

        // getUsers return Flowable<List<User>>
        dbUser.getUsers().test().assertValueCount(2);
    }

    private SampleDb getMigratedRoomDatabase() {
        SampleDb database =
            Room.databaseBuilder(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), SampleDb.class,
                TEST_DB_NAME).addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_6, MIGRATION_4_6, MIGRATION_5_6).build();
        // close the database and release any stream resources when the test finishes
        testHelper.closeWhenFinished(database);
        return database;
    }

    private void insertUser(User user, SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("userId", user.getUserId());
        // Bunch of other user values
        ...
        db.insert("user", SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE, values);
    }

    private static User createDummyUser(boolean isFirst) {
        User dummy = new User();
        dummy.setData(2);
        return dummy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a log from logcat? I tried the sample and it worked for me.

Comment: @user8035311 Thanks for pointing that out. Looks like the problem is in my migration code. Still investigating though